# How should I change root@mydomain when I send from mail() php function?

Tags: ubuntu, root, alias, sendmail

I've installed sendmail in Ubuntu as below:

```
apt-get install sendmail
```

Then I sent an Email to test, I received Email from `root <root@mydomain>`. I checked the content of `/etc/aliases`, but it was empty. I've looked around but couldn't figure out how to change default user for mail sending. What kind of record should I add to `aliases`?

What I want to achieve is to change root to something like no-reply.

Comment: I think its just a common thing. Didnt you check out [W3Schools](http://www.w3schools.com/php/func_mail_mail.asp)

Comment: Have you checked `/etc/mail/aliases`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can change it when using php `mail()` function, by passing an additional parameter:

```
<?php
mail('receiver@address.com', 'Subject', 'Message', null,
   '-fnoreply@yourdomain.com');
?>
```

Or make it default by changing `sendmail_path` option in `php.ini`:

```
sendmail_path = /usr/sbin/sendmail -t -i -f'noreply@yourdomain.com'
```

Comment: Although injecting `additional parameter` works, it sent the mail to my spam folder! Any solution? Isn't it better to add a record to `aliases` file?

Comment: @phpGeek: I think if mail goes to spam, it's another problem, we can not make any changes here.

Comment: Yeah. It seems that after sending repetitive test emails to my gmail account, it marked my email as spam.

Comment: `gmail` has it own policy to mark a mail is spam or not, you should read through it: https://support.google.com/mail/answer/81126?hl=en. Something I can suggest you that checking encoding of mail, SPF, DKIM, MX, PTR...

Comment: Actually mails were sent to Inbox with no problem until a few seconds ago! I've started the server today.